# dplyr: use a custom function in summarize() when connected to external database

Tags: r, dplyr, amazon-redshift, rpostgresql

Is there a way to use custom functions within a summaries statement when using dplyr to pull data from an external database?
I can’t make usable dummy data because this is specific to databases, but imagine you have a table with three fields: product, true_positive, and all_positive. This is the code I want to use:

```
getPrecision <- function(true_positive, all_positive){
  if_else(sum(all_positive, na.rm = TRUE) == 0, 0,
          (sum(true_positive) / sum(all_positive , na.rm = TRUE)))
}

database_data %>%
    group_by(product) %>%
    summarize(precision = getPrecision(true_positive, all_positive)) %>% collect
```

This is the error: Error in postgresqlExecStatement(conn, statement, ...) :
RS-DBI driver: (could not Retrieve the result : ERROR:  function getprecision(integer, integer) does not exist

Comment: May be try by wrapping with `{{all_positive}}` and `{{true_positive}}` not tested

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To understand the error message, you could use `show_query` instead of `collect` to see the `SQL` code sent to the database :

```
database_data %>%
    group_by(product) %>%
    summarize(precision = getPrecision(true_positive, all_positive)) %>%  
    show_query

<SQL>
SELECT "product", getPrecision("true_positive", "all_positive") AS "precision"
FROM "database_table"
GROUP BY "product"
```

As you can see, this `SQL` expects `getPrecision` function to be available on the server, which is not the case.

A potential solution is to collect table data first, before applying this function in the `R` client:

```
database_data %>%
    collect %>%
    group_by(product) %>%
    summarize(precision = getPrecision(true_positive, all_positive))
```

If this isn't possible, because the table is too big, you'll have to implement the function in `SQL` on the server :

```
SELECT 
  "product", 
  CASE WHEN sum(all_positive)=0 THEN 0 ELSE sum(true_positive)/sum(all_positive) END AS "precision"
FROM "database_table"
GROUP BY "product"
```